# OSL: Parallax Occlusion Mapping

Tags: materials, shaders

I just want to know if this osl file, for a 3ds max, works in blender cycle.

 link: http://www.racoon-artworks.de/?p=773

 osl:http://www.racoon-artworks.de/DownloadableScripts/ParallaxOcclusionMapping_v001.osl
tutorial:https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Parallax-Mapping